# Why does the hologram jump from the TOS Enterprise to the TNG one?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise, star-trek-picard

In *Star Trek Picard*, Jean-Luc enters a Starfleet building and looks up to see a huge hologram of the original Enterprise 1701. The projection then morphs into the Enterprise 1701-D.

Image - side by side comparison

[image: pic of the 2 ships]

Video - (Warning: There is some NSFW language in the later half of the video)

I find it a bit odd for this big, fancy, commemorative display to just skip past the Refit, B, and C Enterprises as if they never existed. Why does it skip them?

Comment: Because those are the famous ones

Comment: Maybe it cycles through 20 other famous Starfleet ships but we only saw it when it showed the two *Enterprise*s.

Comment: Thats also the 25% different Discovery version Constitution class not the classic version.  Real world reason is the classic Trademarks and imagery are allegedly different than what's owned by the current producers.  Consider the merchandise profits from selling the discovery version of the Enterprise.  The classic version gets Kurtzman no cut of the toy sales.
They allegedly would have had to pay license fees for the Galaxy class but to tie Picard to classic TNG justified it. The other starships would not be worth it.

Comment: Also as I recall youtube's trekyards did a close examination of the preview using that scene and the ship names were removed in the cgi though they missed a spot with USS Enterprise on the galaxy model.  Point being those are generic class models not specifically the Enterprise.  A distinction with no difference.

Comment: @lucasbachmann care to weigh in? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/239566/is-there-really-a-rule-that-new-trek-must-25-different-for-legal-reasons

Answer (score -2):

It is possible that the display has a sensor that recognizes people passing though the area.  Possibly Jean-Luc Picard was recognized and the program decided to switch from displaying a Constitution class vessel to displaying a ship that was the same class as one of the ships that Picard had commanded.

Comment: Too bad the art display is more advanced than the receptionist desk.

Comment: This is pure speculation.