# Is there really a rule that new Trek must be 25% different for legal reasons?

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, copyright

In the response to my previous question [Why does the hologram jump from the TOS Enterprise to the TNG one?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/239535/why-does-the-hologram-jump-from-the-tos-enterprise-to-the-tng-one/239552#239552) there was a comment that said the following:

> Thats also the 25% different Discovery version Constitution class not the classic version. Real world reason is the classic Trademarks and imagery are allegedly different than what's owned by the current producers. Consider the merchandise profits from selling the discovery version of the Enterprise. The classic version gets Kurtzman no cut of the toy sales. They allegedly would have had to pay license fees for the Galaxy class but to tie Picard to classic TNG justified it. The other starships would not be worth it.
>
> – lucasbachmann

But is that really true? **Is there in fact a "25% different" rule for Star Trek?**

I started researching this and found the following videos (Note: NSFW language) but I'm not sure what to think at this point.

Comment: This probably sums up the origin accurately without watching a video https://comicbook.com/startrek/news/star-trek-discovery-enterprise-design-legal/  There's what the John Eaves designer of the Discoprise originally said and retracted then the studio saying it was a misunderstanding.  Obviously we don't have access to enough facts to be dogmatic.  But I see no harm in using the phrase to needle Discovery's design choices.

Comment: I'd also note almost certainly the classic Enterprise could be used in Discovery and Picard if CBS wanted.  But it seems obvious that there is no new merchandise opportunities for using the old design so there is an incentive to use a sufficiently distinct design beyond a legal requirement.

Comment: This article but replace J.J. with Kurtzman and Movie merchandise with Discovery and Picard.  I don't see how Kurtzmans company makes a dime from showing the original Enterprise unless it is a distinctly different Enterprise with distinctly different merchandise.   https://www.thewrap.com/how-web-star-trek-rights-killed-jj-abrams-grand-ambitions-91766/

Comment: See https://medium.com/@matthewkadish/star-treks-civil-war-part-3-6cd930008ec3

Comment: How on earth would you even quantify what "25% different" means?